# mootools fire click event. How to pass own data?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a click event to a parent element and delegated the event to its children. However, I want to be able to fire this click and pass in the simulated click event's information to the event listener.

```
$('rt-main').addEvent('click:relay(.catClick)', function(e){
        e.stop();
        new Request({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'index.php?option=com_categories&tmpl=component&view=listing&cat=' + this.get('id'),
            onComplete: function(response){
                $('rt-main').set('html', response);
            }
        }).send();
});

// Here I want to fire the event. But how to pass in 'id' of my choosing?
// I know that this particular line fires the first anchor. How do I target a 
//   psuedo-anchor? Or is it better to target a class?
$('rt-main').fireEvent('click', 
    {target: $('rt-main').getElement('a'), stop: Function.from}
);
```

Comment: well, `this` will be `rt-main` which means you cannot override that unless you use the event object to get `e.target.get('id')` or something, rather than `this.get('id')`. you can also use the event object to pass data by simply adding `id: "foo"` to it and then going `var id = e.id || e.target.get('id');`

Comment: Actually `this` refers to an anchor of class `catClick`. But it works, thanks!

Comment: `this` will differ with mootools version after delegation. if memory serves, it used to be delegator element and got changed around 1.4.x to the the delegate element instead. makes sense to be the delegate element from `.target`

Comment: I noticed the solution doesn't fully work. If the target doesn't yet exist in DOM, the fireEvent doesn't trigger. Is there a way to fire the event in this fashion?

Comment: well. if it does not work, use a saved reference to the method you are calling (instead of anonymous). that way, you can call it whichever way you like but yeah, it will look through matching `childNodes` before it decides if it's worth it to bubble and fire the event callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimitar is correct. You simply pass `id: "data"` in the arguments, and add a check in the event handler for the passed in data.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JT7MG/